# Files larger than 50kb are not sent

Tags: php, telegram-bot, telegram-api

A form has been set up on the site, the data from which is sent to the telegram bot. The PHP script is like this

```
<?php

echo $TOKEN;

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Dotenv\Dotenv;

// Specify the path to the directory where the .env file is located
$dotenvPath = __DIR__;

// Create an instance of Dotenv and load environment variables
$dotenv = Dotenv::createImmutable(dirname(__DIR__));
$dotenv->load();

// Get the token value
$TOKEN = $_ENV['TOKEN'];

// Telegram bot token and channel ID
$TELEGRAM_CHAT_ID = "-1002017740876";

// Check for the presence of a POST request
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    // Collect data from the form
    $product = $_POST['product'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $attachments = $_FILES['attachments'];
    $invoice = $_FILES['invoice'];

    // Save data to the database or file (depends on your requirements)

    // Send notification to Telegram
    $message = "<b>Promindustry</b>\n";
    $message .= "<b>Product Name: </b>".$product." \n";
    $message .= "<b>Sender: </b>".$name." \n";
    $message .= "<b>Phone: </b>".$phone." \n";
    $message .= "<b>Email: </b>".$email;

    file_get_contents("https://api.telegram.org/bot$TOKEN/sendMessage?chat_id=$TELEGRAM_CHAT_ID&parse_mode=html&text=".urlencode($message));

    // Function to send a file to Telegram
    function sendFileToTelegram($document, $caption = '') {
        global $TOKEN, $TELEGRAM_CHAT_ID;

        $url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot$TOKEN/sendDocument";
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, [
            'chat_id' => $TELEGRAM_CHAT_ID,
            'document' => new CURLFile($document['tmp_name'], $document['type'], $document['name']),
            'caption' => $caption
        ]);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $server_output = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
    }

    // Send files to Telegram
    if ($attachments['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        sendFileToTelegram($attachments, 'Attachment: Signboard, part photo, other information');
    }
    if ($invoice['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        sendFileToTelegram($invoice, 'Attachment: Details for invoicing');
    }

    // Send a response to the client (e.g., JSON response)
    echo json_encode([ "status" => "success", "message" => "Form submitted successfully!", ]);

} else {
    // Send a response to the client about the invalid request method
    echo json_encode(["status" => "error", "message" => "Invalid request method!"]);
}
?>
```

The problem is that everything works fine as long as the file is less than 50 kilobytes in size. As soon as the file is larger, the form is not sent.
I will be grateful for your help in solving this problem.

I tried to redo the script

Could there be an error in the handler here?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#tg").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        // Sending data to the backend using AJAX
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "process_form.php",
            data: new FormData(this),
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function(response) {
                // Handling a successful response
                console.log(response);

                // Display a success message to the user
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                // Handling an error
                console.error(xhr.responseText);

                // Display an error message to the user
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: What is behaviour of code if file size is greater than 50kb? Please provide with error messages if any of them is shown.

Comment: @ZaidMalek No errors occur, everything is done the same way as when sending smaller files

Comment: I've tried your code and it works perfectly fine for me.
my ini configuration upload_max_filesize = 2M 
post_max_size = 8M

Comment: @ZaidMalek Can there be any errors in my handler? I added the code to the initial message.

Answer (score 0):

Most probable reason for such behaviour can be your ***php.ini*** configuration.

Please locate your ***php.ini*** file and edit this two lines according to your requirements.

```
upload_max_filesize = 64M (change size as per your project requirement)
post_max_size = 64M
```

Also verify file limitations from telegram api if there are any

Comment: Default upload size is `2MB`

Comment: It happens that people change size while checking online solutions and then forget. So I suggested to verify it

Comment: In the file info.php it is indicated as follows - upload_max_filesize 5000M 5000M

Comment: I don't think anyone would lower the upload size from the 2MB default size to anything lower - Furthermore OP is experiencing this when *sending* the attachment to an API - not the server itself